# Can a phrase begin with adjective followed by a preposition?

Tags: phrases

I read the following sentence recently.

> To his right the valley continued in its sleepy beauty, mute and understated, its wildest autumn colors blunted by the distance, **placid as water color by an artist who mixed all his colors with brown.** (Joyce Carol Oates, "The Secret Marriage"). https://www.thoughtco.com/absolute-phrase-grammar-1689049

I'm wondering whether the bolded part is a phrase that began with an adjective followed by a preposition; however, it seems that none of the types of phrase (Gerund Phrases, Noun Phrases, Verb Phrases, etc) describes that usage.

Comment: The scene is being compared to a painting - '[as] placid as [a] water color'. When using the phrase 'as [adjective] as', it is possible to leave out the first _as_.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Could you please tell us what your research has found? The bolded phrase is a simile (placid *as* a watercolor). The bolded phrase is also an adjective phrase, with the head adjective *placid* modifying *autumn colors*. And yes, one can have a preposition immediately following an adjective.

Comment: *Happy as a clam*. Check.